# Find values in string using awk

Tags: bash, unix, awk, sh

I am new to shell scripting. I am trying pick all the fields value from string if it matches with the another string. For example i have a string like

```
Mobile:25:15000#TV:10:20000#Laptop:20:65000
```

and another string is `TV` then my code should pick data from  `TV:10:20000` same if the another string is `Mobile` then it should pick `Mobile:25:15000`.

The code so far I have written is as below:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
x="Mobile:25:15000#TV:10:20000#Laptop:20:65000"
y="Laptop"
o_str=$(echo "$x"| awk -F "#" 'BEGIN{OFS="\n"} {if ($1== $y) print } y=$y');
echo $o_str
```

I know I am doing something wrong but cant able to figure it out. Can someone tell me where am I going wrong?

Comment: _if it matches with the another string_ is not accurate enough. Does `aTVb` _match_ `TV`?

Comment: No its should not match.

Comment: Then please edit your question and make it clear: in your first input string fields are separated by `#`, themselves with sub-fields separated by colons and you do not search a field that "_matches_" the second string, you search a field that has a sub-field exactly equal to the second string. And if the equal sub-field shall be only the first, please add also this information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```sh
o_str=$(awk -v y="$y" -F: 'BEGIN{RS="#"} $1 == y' <<< "$x");
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/ciMmxY):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
x="Mobile:25:15000#TV:10:20000#Laptop:20:65000"
y="Laptop"
o_str=$(awk -v y="$y" -F: 'BEGIN{RS="#"} $1 == y' <<< "$x");
echo "$o_str"
## => Laptop:20:65000
```

*Details*:

- `-v y="$y"` - pass tje `y` variable to `awk` script
- `-F:` - the field separator is set to a `:` char
- `BEGIN{RS="#"}` - record separator is set to a `#` char
- `$1 == y` - if Field 1 value is equal to `y` variable value, print this record.

Answer (score 2):

How about a bash solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

x="Mobile:25:15000#TV:10:20000#Laptop:20:65000"
y="Laptop"
IFS=# read -r -a ary <<< "$x"           # split $x on "#" into array "ary"
for i in "${ary[@]}"; do                # loop over the elements of ary
    if [[ $i = $y* ]]; then             # if $y starts with an element
        echo "$i"                       # then print the element
    fi
done
```

Output:

```
Laptop:20:65000
```

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code. Simple explanation would be, creating an `awk` variable named `var` which has value of bash variable `y` in it. In main program using `match` which has regex `var":[^:]*:[^#]*` in it, matching variable value will look till 2 values of colons till `#` is found and then printing matched value.

```
y="Laptop"
o_str=$(awk -v var="$y" 'match($0,var":[^:]*:[^#]*"){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}' Input_file)
```

When we print variable output will be as follows:

```
echo "$o_str"
Laptop:20:65000
```

Comment: This one is working fine for y as Laptop but when i give y as TV it picks TV:10:20000#Laptop:20:65000 and that is not correct

Comment: @Tarun, kindly do check my edited solution, that will work with both the cases, do let me know in case of any queries.